# load matlab data file

Tags: matlab, enums, constants

I would like to set in a file all constant,parameters and then I can access from another class to any variable

for example const file const.m

```
FILE='file';
EDIT='edit';
COLOR_RED ='red',
COLOR_BLUE ='Blue'
START ='Start'
.....
...
```

and from any other files if I would like to access to any variable :

```
a = const.EDIT
```

so that I haven't to set a ='file' in each file.

How could I do that with matlab ? 
how could also use enumeration ?

Comment: If you just use save() when you have no toher variables in the workspace except these, then when you go load('myfile.mat', EDIT) it will create a variable in your workspace called EDIT. You don't need to go a = load(...), but you should for readability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a struct just use the save command: http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/save.html and specify which workspace variables you want to save. If there are small like in your example, they will be easy to read in notepad for access not in matlab. In matlab just use the load function.

For example create two variable in matlab:

```
Var1 = 'Red'
Var2 = [1 2; 3 4]
```

now type

```
save('myData.mat');
```

this should create a file called myData.mat in your current working folder.

Now in another Matlab script you want to set a variable to have the value you saved as Var1 so you can go

```
NewVar = load('myData.mat', Var1)
```

And you can easily edit the values in the .mat file in a text editor such as notepad or gedit (or emacs or ms word or whatever) if you add the -ascii parameter when saving.

But you can also rewrite a variable by using save() again and specifying the variable name.

Comment: in fact I wantn't to use save , this is not what I wnat to do, I just declare all parameters and some constants in a file and from other files I access when needed to the const file to get the variable name so that my development is robust if any I change the variable name or value, I have just to modify the value in const file and not in all files.

Comment: Open Matlab, create the constants you want as variables and then type save with the filename you want. check it out in notepad, it should be very easy to manually edit in the future and that way you can use load whenever you want to get access to a variable. Load can load a single variable from a .mat file containing many, it sounds fine for what you have described. But seriously, save in matlab, check out the .mat file in notepad and you will see what I mean.

Comment: Otherwise you could try xmlread() and xmlwrite but I think it is unnecessary for you, especially if you are working in matlab. Save is the way to go.

Comment: Dan, I'm not really familar , and Iwant to do it in ".m" file not interactively, could you refine please ?

Comment: I've create a variable File ='File' in workspace and save in file data.mat , now from any other matlab file I should call load('data.mat') each time ? I don't understant what do you mean by checkout in notpad ?

Comment: navigate to the folder where 'data.mat' is stored on your computer and open it in a text editor. If you are using windows, right click and select open with and choose notepad form the list of programs. I'll edit my answer wrt to the load syntax

Comment: sure but this is done interactively.I want to access to data by command line notby browsing manually.

Comment: this is all by the command line... I'm just saying that if you wanted to edit the saved file without opening matlab you can. If you want to edit it from the command line then just use save() again with the same file name...

Comment: Dan,this is what I I've did : I've  created a variable FILE in workspace having 'File' as value then I save it data.mat , now if I open browser and edit the mat file with notepad++ ist' crypted ! what I want to do is juste to access easely to variables in the data file.

Comment: Sorry you need to specify -ascii if you want to read it. Besides you have said you want access only through the command line so try using save() and load() like in my edited answer, does that not work for you? You can leave notepad out of this, I thought you wanted to edit the file outside of matlab like a config file, but since you don't save() and load() are all you need

Comment: thanks Dan , do you know if it's possible to use xpath within Matlab? I would like to compare,read,get some informations from xml files ?

Comment: I've never done that before, but I'm sure it's possible. But it's off topic so you must create a new question.